# Ruby on Rails create new object with param from another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, object, search, methods

I have my search method and I want to pass my "search" to a analysis object. The search that user is looking will be the name of the analysis so as an Admin I can see the analysis and discovery what the users are most searching.

Here is my methods. My @analysis.name is always create with nil value. Does any body know how to fix that?

```
def search_articles
    @search_param = params[:current_search][:search]
    @articles = Article.where("title LIKE :search", 
    :search => "%#{params[:current_search][:search]}%")

    search_attribute = :search
    update_analysis(search_attribute)
  end

  def update_analysis(search)
    @analysis = Analysis.create([{name: search, search_number: 1}])
  end
```

Comment: Does your Analysis intializer really need the params as an array of hashes? I'm talking about this snippet `[{name: search, search_number: 1}]`

Comment: not really, this was that fast copy and past and I forgot to erase then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: 
replace

```
search_attribute = :search
```

to

```
search_attribute = params[:current_search][:search]
```